# Conversion between workflow Xaml and workflow dll

Tags: xaml, workflow, converters, workflow-foundation-4

This is a workflow novice question from me.  Is there any way to simply convert a workflow XAML file into a Workflow dll file, and therefore use the result as an activity in the activity toolbox of  the workflow designer?

Thanks in adavnce.

Comment: Not really.  While a workflow defined in an xaml file can be treated like any Activity, it doesn't have a designer and the activities contained within it won't be visible/editable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ActivityXamlServices.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370946.aspx) to transform your XAML into an activity and do whatever you want with it.

Having a designer for it is a little bit trickier. Like @Will said, I doubt designer reference can be saved on XAML, so the workflow designer won't have any information about it and it will show the default one.